# How to set response status code in Filter when controller returns ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I'm developing a simple Spring Boot application with servlet filter, that intended to set response status code:

```
@Component
public class TestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        response.setStatus(201);
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
```

Everything goes as expected (status is 201) if controller returns a String. But if controller returns a ResponseEntity, then after calling doFilter() status code is 200 instead of 201:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/string")
    public String testString() {
        return "OK"; // status code is 201 as set by Filter
    }
}

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/entity")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testResponseEntity() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("OK"); // status code is 200
    }
}
```

Why filter doesn't change status code when using ResponseEntity?

--

Project on Github: https://github.com/timofeev-denis/set-status-code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the `/string` endpoint, you're not modifying the status code. With the `/entity` endpoint, you explicitly are (you're setting it to 200 by virtue of returning an ok).

Your filter implementation changes the response status code and **then** proceeds to run the rest of the filter chain -- and [then the servlet](http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/as10g/101300/B25221_03/web.1013/b14426/filters.htm). And we just established the servlet (your controller) is setting the response status code to something else.

So you need to change the response code **after** the servlet/controller has done its thing.

Your first thought might be to reimplement your filter like this:

```
@Component
public class TestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        } finally {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

            response.setStatus(205);
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, that won't work either! According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc):

> Note that postHandle is less useful with @ResponseBody and
>   ResponseEntity methods for which the response is written and committed
>   within the HandlerAdapter and before postHandle. That means it is too
>   late to make any changes to the response, such as adding an extra
>   header. For such scenarios, you can implement ResponseBodyAdvice and
>   either declare it as an Controller Advice bean or configure it
>   directly on RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.

This might have the desired effect you're looking for (note I set to "CHECKPOINT" just to demonstrate the point!):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class TestResponseBodyAdvice<T> implements ResponseBodyAdvice<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T beforeBodyWrite(T body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        //
        // insert status code of choice here
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.CHECKPOINT);

        return body;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're a life-saver! Thank you. I spent hours trying to find a solution to this until I came across this. (My problem was a little different from the OP's, but solution was the same.)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states the `ResponseEntity#ok` returns a HTTP OK (https://httpstatuses.com/200) status code. The filter is running earlier so the status is later overwritten.

You should create the `ResponseEntity` using some other means described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html.